# F# dynamic operator with special left argument

Tags: dynamic, f#

In the following F# snippet

```
let (?) (map : Map<string, string>) (key : string) = map.[key]

let map = [("aKey", "aValue"); ("another Key", "another Value")] |> Map.ofList

let a = map.["aKey"]
let b = map?aKey
assert (a = b)

let c = map.["another Key"] //OK
let d = map?another Key //How should this be written?
assert (c = d)
```

what is the correct syntax for line `let d = map?...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# have special operator, that makes invalid identifier valid. There's no much information about this operator in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/), there's no even name for it

```
``...``
```

I would call it double backtic. It's used mostly for data access, for example

```ml
// process CSV file with header "Production year,Make,Model"

type Cars = CsvProvider<"file.csv">
let sample = Cars.GetSample()
for row in sample.Rows do
    row.``Production year`` |> printfn "%d"
```

In your example, you can access keys with

```ml
let d = map?``another key``
```

C# compiler makes public method `<Clone>$` for records. It have such strange name, so nobody would ever try to access it, but we can from F#

```ml
let myRecord = ...;
let copyOfRecords = myRecord.``<Clone>$``()
```

Roslyn team tried to hide this member intentionally, so don't use this code, just know that this is possible.

Comment: I know double backtick, just didn't come to mind to use it here.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you intend

```
let (?) (map : Map<string, string>) (key : string) = map.[key]

let map = [("aKey", "aValue"); ("another Key", "another Value")] |> Map.ofList

let a = map.["aKey"]
let b = map ? ("aKey") 
let b = map?aKey // alternative, as you wrote it
assert (a = b)

let c = map.["another Key"] 
let d = map ? ("another Key") // here the lexer requires " and even brackets
assert (c = d)
```